# ARP Retry count exceeded (after uBooting)

Tags: u-boot, arp, vxworks, nxp-microcontroller

I am working with i.Mx6 by NXP with vXworks and uBoot on it.
Generally, the program is loaded via the SD card, though whilst I am debugging I upload the vXworks file via TFTP.

In the past, I didn't experience any problems with it, though a few months ago it began to be very annoying since I always get this error after uBoot finishes its process:

[image: Error in TeraTerm]

The things it, that when I turn off and on the power supply a few times - it does manage to load the files and start the program correctly.

I was trying to replace cards, cables, I turned off the anti-virus, also changed the computer and TFTP server software - nothing helped.
Any ideas someone?

Thanks!

Comment: Please, provide the following information: version of U-Boot used, failing command.

Comment: U-Boot 2015.04-00142-g22d418b (May 30 2016 - 14:40:32). What do you mean by falling command? It falls while it is trying to load the vXworks file from TFTP and start the program.

Comment: Is the problem reproducible with current upstream U-Boot?